# Django error logging only working in debug mode

Tags: django

When getting a django.request error my logging only writes into the log file when running with DEBUG=True. With DEBUG=False nothing gets written.
Here is my LOGGING definition:

```
def skip_static_requests(record):
    if record.args[0].startswith('GET /static/'):  # filter whatever you want
        return False
    return True

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse',
        },
        'require_debug_true': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugTrue',
        },
        'skip_static_requests': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.CallbackFilter',
            'callback': skip_static_requests,
        },
    },
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': "%(asctime)s [%(schema_name)s] %(levelname)s [%(name)s:%(lineno)s] %(message)s",
            'datefmt': "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': '/var/log/mylog.log',
            'filters': ['skip_static_requests'],
            'formatter': 'verbose'
        },
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
        },
        'null': {
            'class': 'logging.NullHandler',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.security.DisallowedHost': {
            'handlers': ['null'],
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['file', 'mail_admins'],
            'propagate': True,
            'level': config('LOG_LEVEL', default='INFO'),
        },
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['file', 'mail_admins'],
            'propagate': True,
            'level': 'ERROR',
        }
    }
}
```

Anyone who has a clue what could be wrong? My feeling is that it has nothing to do with the LOGGING definition.

Comment: I finally found the solution. I have changed the level to 'INFO' for django.request logger. But why is django creating different log levels for the same error when in debug=True vs False?   debug=True issues an ERROR level and debug=False an INFO level.

Comment: @BijinAbraham - Link does not work. Please update / remove. Thanks.